# Pass parameter from Gridview column to Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I need to pass an argument (which comes from my database) from a radgrid view column to my javascript (which opens a dialog box window). However, I can't put the "bind("Id")" as a parameter from where I call the javascript as href.

In simpler words, I am looking for a way to pass <% Bind("Id")%> to the javascript, OpenMyWindow, call instead of the hardcoded, 111, right now.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Meet" DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Meet">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>' href="javascript: OpenMyWindow(111);" Width="30%">
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

When I try "OnClick" instead of "href", my popup dialog box closes instantly and doesn't stay opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "OnClientClick" and return false from your javascript method to prevent post back.

Alternatively. You could use a method passing in the DataIten. Then output an anchor tag created anyway you like:

```
 <%# formatOpener(Container.DataItem) %>
```

With code behind of:

```
protected string formatOpener(object item)
{
      ObjectType myObj = (ObjectType)item;
      return String.Format("<a href=\"javascript:OpenMyWindow({0});\" width=\"30%\"/>{1}</a>", myObj.ID, myObj.subject);
}
```

Comment: With OnClientClick, how do I pass an argument? "Command Argument" seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a `LinkButton`, you could achieve it with an `asp:HyperLink` (which renders as a `a` tag):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript: OpenMyWindow(" +  Eval("ID").ToString() + ");" %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Also, don't use `Bind` if you don't need it, for displaying purposes always use `Eval`.

Answer (score 0):

User HyperLink control instead and try setting the [NavigateUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the HyperLink this way:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "javascript: OpenMyWindow({0});")%>'>
```

hope it helps./.

Comment: What are you saying that I didnt previously?

Comment: Oh, let me know if I should even care about it. I just made a proper use of Eval() method overloads.

Comment: The essence of your answer is the same, this site is about providing collaborative knowledge not copying for auto-glorify. The collaborative part means that, if you have an improvement suggestion on to another user answer, you can actually suggest it using the comments. By the way, a suggestion to yours: you missed an unnecesary `Bind` on the `Subject` field that could be better done with `Eval`. Bests of luck ;)

Comment: well, I use Bind or Eval that is my choice. Another things that if you think that I copied your answer, then pity you! I am here to contribute something. Let me do myself (which is of course, none of your business) and do your business soulfully. And by the way, one more time to you.. I find is drastically ridiculous when you can think that somebody can copy your answer for such an easy question. the big LOL

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out and solved this issue. Actually, somebody told me on the other post that, CommandArgument is completely a server-side property and doesn't render any html attribute. So I can't change any button's attribute and fire click on it. I finally made "Id" come through the code behind and made it work.

aspx code

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="Subject" DataTextField="Subject" HeaderText="Meeting">
             <HeaderStyle Width="30%" />
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

Code Behind

```
var subjectLink = meetingRow["Subject"].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
subjectLink.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript: return OpenMyWindow('" + meetingId + "')");
```